# Operator '===' cannot be applied to types '"x"' and 'y'. In ternary operator

Tags: typescript

I have an ternary operator inside one of my arrays:

```
this.columns = [
  {
    name: 'item' === 'list' ? 'list' : 'n/a' 
  }
];
```

It seems that TypeScript thinks that

`: 'item'`

is me declaring its type so its throwing an error. Is there another way to write this ternary operator so I don't get this error?

### Edit

I understand that `'item' === 'list'` is always false. It needs to be in this format due to the library I am using. The left hand side is matching with a property of the library:

```
{
  item: 'list'
}
```

Comment: You can force `item` and `list` to be string with `'item' as string === 'list' as string ? 'list' : 'n/a'`

Comment: `'item' === 'list'` is false, so you can just replace the whole expression by `'n/a'`.

Comment: have you tried to set parenthesis?

Comment: Please elaborate your use case a bit more. What do you mean by "The left hand side is matching with a property of the library"? Are you generating TypeScript code? If not, what exactly does your library return from which method calls or what does it expect?

Comment: so i have a library that spits out items that have the data `{item: 'list'}` and I am doing stuff with that data in a seperate file with `this.columns`

Comment: So are you saying that this expression isn't really executed as-is? So it isn't really typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You get a compilation error because `'item' === 'list'` will always return false. You are comparing 2 literals here.

This will compile if you use variables instead of literals.

```
var item = 'item';
this.columns = [
  {
    name: item === 'list' ? 'list' : 'n/a' 
  }
];
```

EDIT:

The object should be assigned to something. Let's name it props:

```
const props = {
  item: 'list'
}

this.columns = [
  {
    name: props.item === 'list' ? 'list' : 'n/a' 
  }
];
```

Comment: Your example works because when writing `var item = 'item';` or `let item = 'item';` TypeScript will infer that `item` has type `string` - it does that to allow you to assign other strings to that variable. As soon as you switch to `const item = 'item';` it will show its full type inference capabilities and will assume `item` to be of the literal type `"item"` which is stronger than `string`.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that he probably wants to use a variable, otherwise he should just write `name: 'n/a'`

Comment: Edited my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has the notion of [literal types](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html).
You are testing two different literals for equality - this is impossible, because the types (literal types!) are different. You may only compare objects which MAY be equal.

Have a look at this example, which has the same flaw:

```
const x = 'item';
const y = 'list';
const test = (x === y);
```

The TypeScript compiler will complain about this at the part `x === y` because `x` has the type (and value) `"item"` and `y` has the type (and value) `"list"`.

Those literal string types are subtypes of `string` but the equality operator requires more - `x` of type `X` can only be compared by `===` to `y` of type `Y` if the type inference sees no contradiction in assuming that an object might be of type `X` and `Y` at the same time (for example it's fine, if `Y` is a subtype of `X`).

The message `Operator  '===' cannot be applied to types '"item"' and '"list"'` yo got is showing that.

At TypeScript 3.0+ you'll get another message which is easier to understand: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"item"' and '"list"' have no overlap.`

Notice that the following will work because you are explicitely hiding some type information:

```
const x: string = 'item'; // x is only declared as SOME string
const y = 'list';
const test = (x === y);
```

In your example you might write:

```
const columns = [
  {
    name: 'item' === 'list' as string ? 'list' : 'n/a' 
  }
];
```

Comment: hello thanks for your answer!, but it does not seem to work for me. can you check my new edit?

Comment: Ok, after your edit this answer is obsolete. It focuses on the problems arising from strict typing. You actual problem is accessing the data. See my other answer for a solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635698/10245948

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question after you have edited it, you are in the following situation:

From some call you got an object, let's call it `obj` which contains

```
{
   item: 'list'
}
```

and maybe there are more properties in `obj` beside `item`.

Now you want to create an array (supposedly column definitions) whose contents depend on the value of the property `item` in `obj`.
You tried to get the value of that property by simple writing `'item'` - it doesn't work like this. To do it right, write:

```
this.columns = [
  {
    name: obj.item === 'list' ? 'list' : 'n/a' 
  }
];
```

Notice how the property `item` of `obj` is explicitly accessed by writing `obj.item`!